# My mobile responsive website is not resizing properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, responsive-design

i have a website in development phase. The default view looks fine, but when the browser is re-sized, instead of being gracefully responsive, the images and fonts looks too stretched or squeezed. I have attached two images here. Pls advice what is wrong. Thank You.[image: Image at default browser view][image: re-sized browser view]

Comment: What you use to make site responsive?

Comment: Have you added viewport in your code? And give a link to your site or make a Fiddle.

Comment: are you using bootstrap for responsive web-site?

Answer (score 0):

If the image is the background, trying adding:

```
background-size: cover;
```

to those divs.

This will make the image large enough to fill its container while maintaining the original ratio.

If the image is just an img and not the background-image, if you switch it, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

When you add this CSS with your background image it take `100% width` in all browser size. Image not stretch after adding this css.

```
background-position: center center; 
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
background-attachment: fixed; 
background-size: cover; 
height: 100%; 
width: 100%;
```

Comment: Sure.
When you add this css with your background image it take 100% width in all browser size. Image not stretch after adding this css.

background-position: center center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;

Comment: fine,but put that description in your answer next time